# Handling screen density for web apps

Tags: android, android-webview

I've written a very simple Android app which basically presents a full screen `WebView` (no title bar, notification bar or URL bar) in landscape.

The `Activity` then basically loads a `client.html` file from the user's PC which then loads a fixed image meant to fill the whole of the screen. The `client.html` file has a `meta` element as follows...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

In the `<html><body>` the `<img>` `src` attribute is set by requesting the image at a specific size as follows...

```
<div id="BasicDemo" >
    <img id="nscreen" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">setImageSource()</script>
```

...and this is the javascript `setImageSource()`...

```
function setImageSource() {
    $.getScript("myscript.js", function() {
        $("#nscreen").attr("src", "/control?size=" + getDimensions());
    });
}
```

The `getDimensions()` function is another piece of javascript which calls into the Android app and retrieves the 'absolute' screen dimensions in pixels.

So here's my problem (and I know using absolute pixels is probably the root of it)....

On my Desire, it's classed as hdpi for web apps and has 800x480 actual pixels. The call to set the image source looks like...`"/control?size=800x480"` and works perfectly. The image fits my full screen. One tester, however, has a 7in tablet - also 800x480 but due to screen size it's classed as mdpi. Requesting the same sized image with `"/control?size=800x480"` and the fact the `<meta>` tag forces mdpi obviously means the image is oversized.

So the question - I'm forced to specify dimensions when requesting the image source - how am I supposed to translate things properly? Has anyone a similar experience they can share?

I've read [Targeting Screens from Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) several times over and I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS media queries to target LDPI, MDPI and HDPI:
http://designbycode.tumblr.com/post/1127120282/pixel-perfect-android-web-ui